# ACS60010: No claims other than authentication instant and authentication method were generated during rules processing

Tags: namespaces, controls, acs

I am trying to use ACS as fereration provider and local AD + ADFS as identity provider.

### checked fiddler and showing ADFS is returning token, but ACS is not issuing a token for me. see the error message.

HTTP status 403

Message:  ACS50000: There was an error issuing a token.

Inner Message:  ACS60000: An error occurred while processing rules for relying party 'https:// local host:44302/' using the service identity or identity provider named 'http:// 10. 227. 125. 110/adfs/services/trust'.

### Inner Message:  ACS60010: No claims other than authentication instant and authentication method were generated during rules processing.

When I am trying with ADFS as identity and federation provider both, Its returning 6 claims and my application shows them correctly.

Can any one please help!!!

Comment: instead doing it manually, added ACS as RP trust in ADFS using metadata link and worked fine...

Answer (score 0):

instead doing it manually, added ACS as RP trust in ADFS using metadata link and worked fine..